# Check if key exists in multiple array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The mysql result is the following array

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [customs_tariff_number] => 
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [customs_tariff_number] => 
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [customs_tariff_number] => 
      )

  [3] => Array
      (
          [customs_tariff_number] => 123456789
      )
)
```

I the key [customs_tariff_number] is not empty I would like to do a if condition to draw a tablerow like this

```
if (in_array('customs_tariff_number', $array)) {
  echo '<tr>rowname</tr>';
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `foreach($array as $arr) {
   if (!empty($arr['customs_tariff_number'])) {
     echo '<tr>rowname</tr>';
   }
}` ?

Comment: This works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with `array_walk_recursive`

```
     function check($value, $key){
    if($key === 'customs_tariff_number'){
         echo '<tr>rowname</tr>';
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($a, 'check');
```